# Variable scope in Android

Tags: android, variables, scope

i'm new to android and i'm having some trouble accessing variables within an application. ive tried accessing it in the onClick method but its giving me erros. how do i read it?
here is the simplyfied code:

```
public class DBDetails extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dbdetails);
        new fetchDBDetails(this).execute();

        Button ButtonCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCall);
        ButtonCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //READING VALUE BELOW
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phone)), 1);
           }
        });
      }
}

    class fetchDBDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private DBDetails fetchDBDetailsContext = null;
        String phone;

        public fetchDBDetails(DBDetails context) {
            fetchDBContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    phone = "12345678"; //ASSIGNING VALUE HERE
        }
    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have different issues here.
First, the user may click the button before your ASyncTask finishes (race condition).

`phone` is a member of `fetchDBDetails` and is not accessible as just `phone' in`DBDetails`

You need to somehow pass the phone variable back from the `fetchDBDetails` class to your `DBDetails` class.

**EDIT**:

You can add a public member variable `public String phone` in `DBDetails` and do

```
fetchDatenbankDetailsContext.phone = telefon;
```

at the end of `onPostExecute()`

Comment: you cant press the button before it finished because the asynctask gets triggered on the start of the activity and the whole UI is hidden until everything is loaded. how can i pass it do DBDetails?

Comment: @robs Hard to say without seeing more of the code but maybe by passing some data back to `DBDetails` in the `onPostExecute()` function of your ASyncTask